# How do I hide which-func from powerline in 24.5?

Tags: mode-line, powerline

I'm having trouble hiding the display of `which-func` from powerline. I'm successfully showing it in the header, but it stubbornly won't be removed from powerline. I've tried the following:

```el
(setq mode-line-format (delete (assoc 'which-func-mode
                                      mode-line-format) mode-line-format))

(setq mode-line-misc-info (delete (assoc 'which-func-mode
                                         mode-line-misc-info) mode-line-misc-info)

(setq mode-line-format (assq-delete-all 'which-func-mode mode-line-format))

(setq mode-line-misc-info (assq-delete-all 'which-func-mode mode-line-misc-info))
```

Also tried the following, hooking into various points around both powerline and which-func:

```el
(powerline-which-func 'which-func nil)
(powerline-raw which-func-format nil 'l)
```

I've had this working in the past, but no joy this time round.

Halp?

Comment: It might help if you post the value of `mode-line-format` and `mode-line-misc-info` to identify what needs to be removed.

Comment: Apologies to @lunaryorn, et al; I didn't realise I needed to specify I have powerline enabled. Question updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```el
(let ((which-func '(which-func-mode ("" which-func-format " "))))
   (setq-default mode-line-format (remove which-func mode-line-format))
   (setq-default mode-line-misc-info (remove which-func mode-line-misc-info))
   (setq-default header-line-format which-func))
```

It removes `which-func` from the mode-line, and place it in the header.

Comment: Unfortunately this also doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @unpluggd Assuming the default setup this would work.  If it doesn't, your mode line setup is probably very different from the default.  Would you mind to edit your question and add the values of the relevant variables?

Comment: Thanks @lunaryorn. I was assuming the default setup, although this works with `smart-mode-line` too.